# Has 10.6.7 broken the built-in Cisco IPSec VPN client?

Tags: snow-leopard, vpn

No longer able to connect to my Cisco VPN using 10.6.7. No configuration changes have happened and another machine still on 10.6.6 works correctly.

If you've experienced this and resolved the issue, please advise.

Comment: I find the snow leopard built-in client to be much better - had a variety of issues with the Cisco one including kernel panics. No bother at all since switching, and much faster to connect.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using -- or was using -- the built-in client.

Comment: OK - that wasn't clear in your question - I assume you've rebooted and problem is still there? Occassionally the vpn process (racoon) gets in a state where it won't connect, but either killing the process or restarting fixes that. Have you looked at the logs - filter on 'racoon' in the system log in console.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the same issue, but I've had problems with the 10.7 built-in Cisco IPSec client from within my work network - there are some cryptic references (i.e. tech-speak I don't understand) to what Apple changed at the bottom of this [support discussion](https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2095921).

Switching over to a tethered 3G connection fixed the problem. I mention it here in case someone stumbles across this page & it helps them.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the Cisco client doesn't work in 64bit mode, so you need to reboot and hold down the 3 and 2 keys whilst booting to boot into 32bit mode.   That should make it work.

Info [here](http://www.cisco.com/web/software/282364316/43859/4.9.1.0280-rel-notes.txt).

Comment: But isn't that just the stand alone Cisco VPN Clint that doesn't work in 64-bit mode - the build-in VPN Client should work AFAIK

Comment: Thanks. I had been using the built-in client along with running the 64-bit kernel for about 6 months now w/o any problems.